# Reuse base() constructor argument in this() constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructors, type-casting

Let's say I have two classes `Base` and `Derived : Base`.

`Derived` shall be able to use a `DerivedComponent : BaseComponent`,
just like all other derivates of `Base` use their own derivate specific component.
All these `BaseComponent` components, like `DerivedComponent`, have some common functionality accessible
in `Base`.

Since I don't want to downcast this `BaseComponent` every time I use `DerivedComponent` functionality in `Derived`, I also added its reference as `DerivedComponent` to `Derived`.

```
class Base
{
    private BaseComponent component;

    protected Component
    {
        get { return component; }
    }

    Base(BaseComponent component)
}

class Derived : Base
{
    private DerivedComponent component;

    Derived() : base(new DerivedComponent())
    {
        this.component = (DerivedComponent) base.Component;
    }
}

class BaseComponent {}

class DerivedComponent : BaseComponent {}
```

Is it necessary to do it this way, with the downcast?
Can't I somehow reuse the argument from `base()` and assign it directly to my `Derived`'s component?

Comment: Sorry, but "*Questions asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code are off-topic here*". If you want to ask questions generally about inheritance, then they would be on topic. You could ask this question on Stack Overflow instead. Be warned that it'll likely be marked as a duplicate, but that duplicate will provide you your answer. Weird system, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use constructor chaining to pass the dependency to a separate constructor in `Derived`, and then both pass that to the base constructor and set the field value:

```
class Base
{
    private BaseComponent component;

    protected Component
    {
        get { return component; }
    }

    Base(BaseComponent component)
}

class Derived : Base
{
    private DerivedComponent component;

    Derived() : this(new DerivedComponent())
    { }

    Derived(DerivedComponent component) : base(component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```